# Include a service in a SDK/library

Tags: java, android, service, sdk, aidl

I've gotten an android service written as a stand-alone APK and I'm trying to include this in the SDK so it automatically installs the service through some publicly exposed function from the SDK.

Is there a way to achieve this?

For instance, the SDK is monitor.jar which has helper functions.
The service is GetCurrentMonitor.apk which runs a background service that returns the value of some stock currently monitoring.

Now, I want to release the SDK so that when it's included in some 3rd party app, it automagically installs the background service for GetCurrentMonitor project...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing. Here is my interpretation of what you are asking:

> I have an Android application that has a service. I have a separate SDK (JAR or Android library project). I want users of the SDK to be able to call a function and have the APK containing the service be downloaded and installed.

This is possible, sorta.

You can have code in your JAR that either:

- call `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for the `market:` `Uri` pointing to your app on Google Play, or
- downloads an APK from some server of yours to external storage, then calls `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` pointing to that downloaded APK, to kick off an install

In either case, the user will need to get involved in the installation process -- you cannot install apps silently. And, in the latter case, you will be responsible for handling your own updates over time.

This also will tend to confuse the user, as they may not realize why your app is floating around their device, so you will need to be able to handle the case where they uninstall it.

Also, it is possible that on Android 3.1+, the user will need to launch an activity of yours before your service will be usable. With luck, that is not required, though I cannot rule it out at this time.

And, of course, if I did not correctly understand your question, please consider editing the question to clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish.